# SharePoint Search Display Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, display-template

I am working on Office 365 and I need to fetch Value of Location, Start date and End Date fields (Calendar fields) in Search Display Template (Item_CommonItem_Body.html). But everytime it returns Either null or undefined.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with these crawled properties not being mapped correctly to Managed Properties by default.  In Site Administration > Search Schema, this is what I have done:

1. RefinableDate01 – This is a SharePoint provided Managed Property of Type = Date that is provided for configuration.  It should be mapped to the Crawled Properties: “ows_q_DATE_EventDate” and “ows_EventDate”.  This is the Start Date field in a Calendar.
2. RefinableDate02 - This is another SharePoint provided Managed Property of Type = Date that is provided for configuration.  It should be mapped to the Crawled Properties: “ows_q_DATE_EndDate” and “ows_EndDate”.  This is the End Date field in a Calendar.

My guess is that you could do the same for Location.  Also make sure that the calendar has been re-indexed after you do your search configuration. I have had to go back into the calendar list settings and under Advanced Settings > Reindex List if the list items have been out there for awhile and are not getting indexed.

Comment: Also, if you have access to the Content Search web part you can easily use the Diagnostic template in that web part to ensure that you are getting values for your specific list fields.